# Hudi throwing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.adapter.Spark2Adapter after upgrading to pyspark 3.4.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-hudi

i recently bumped my pyspark version from 3.3.2 -> 3.4.0 in order to use the `protobuf` library and now I am seeing Hudi throwing all sorts of error. This one particular error is most prevalent. I tried searching for what this `Spark2Adapter` class could be but I have not had any luck.

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o47.listTables.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.adapter.Spark2Adapter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.apache.hudi.SparkAdapterSupport$.sparkAdapter$lzycompute(SparkAdapterSupport.scala:45)
    at org.apache.hudi.SparkAdapterSupport$.sparkAdapter(SparkAdapterSupport.scala:35)
    at org.apache.hudi.SparkAdapterSupport.sparkAdapter(SparkAdapterSupport.scala:29)
    at org.apache.hudi.SparkAdapterSupport.sparkAdapter$(SparkAdapterSupport.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.analysis.HoodieResolveReferences.sparkAdapter$lzycompute(HoodieAnalysis.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.analysis.HoodieResolveReferences.sparkAdapter(HoodieAnalysis.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.analysis.HoodieResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(HoodieAnalysis.scala:482)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.analysis.HoodieResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(HoodieAnalysis.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$3(AnalysisHelper.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.ShowTables.mapChildren(v2Commands.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUp$(AnalysisHelper.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.analysis.HoodieResolveReferences.apply(HoodieAnalysis.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.analysis.HoodieResolveReferences.apply(HoodieAnalysis.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:222)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:211)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$execute$1(Analyzer.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.AnalysisContext$.withNewAnalysisContext(Analyzer.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:526)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.CatalogImpl.listTables(CatalogImpl.scala:118)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I am guessing that I will need to wait for [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HUDI-6198) to happen? The current Hudi bundle i am using is `org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark3.3-bundle_2.12:0.13.1` so i guess that is why I cannot seem to find one for spark 3.4.X?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you’re right. The spark 3.4.0 did cause this issue. However the 0.14.0 version, which is going to be released soon will support Spark 3.4.0.

their unreleased version doc says  0.14.0 will have spark 3.4.0 as default bundle.
https://hudi.apache.org/docs/next/quick-start-guide

https://lists.apache.org/thread/s3cshvlmg01rqpow80qoot6ndg4jgxwc